# Robot framework--> 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: selenium, robotframework

i am facing an error while i am doing  iteration in list.
on first iteration it works fine for me but for second iteration i got an error.

the piece of code is below.

```
@{amt} =    Get WebElements     css=table[id="list2"] td:nth-child(4)
@{tax} =    Get WebElements     css=table[id="list2"] td:nth-child(5)
@{total} =  Get WebElements     css=table[id="list2"] td:nth-child(6)
Set Suite Variable  ${amt}
Set Suite Variable  ${tax}
Set Suite Variable  ${total}
${len} =    Get Length  ${total}
:FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE    1   10
\   ${AMT}      ${dec}      Split String        ${amt[${i}].text}   .
\   ${TAX}      ${dec}      Split String        ${tax[${i}].text}   .
\   ${TOTAL}    ${dec}      Split String        ${total[${i}].text} .

\   ${AMT} =    Convert To Integer  ${AMT}
\   ${TAX} =    Convert To Integer  ${TAX}
\   ${TOTAL} =  Convert To Integer  ${TOTAL}
\   Should Be True  ${AMT}+${TAX}==${TOTAL}
```

*error is-->* Resolving variable '${total[2].text}' failed: TypeError: 'int'          object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in the robotframework variables are not case sensitive, which means.

`${total}` and `${TOTAL}` is same, and in your code you are overwriting the Web Element `${total}` with integer value.

`${TOTAL} =  Convert To Integer  ${TOTAL}`

I would suggest to use the different variable names and your problem will be resolved.